# Angular2 using wrong RouterOutlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I can't seem to get this to work. I am trying to use the md-tabs along with the router-outlet so that I don't preload all data at the same time. Instead, I just load it when it is necessary.

AdminComponent.html

```
<a [routerLink]="['kategorier']"><h1>till kategorier</h1></a>
<md-tab-group (focusChange)="changeTab($event)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of adminPages">
        <md-tab label="{{tab.title}}">
        </md-tab>
    </ng-container>

</md-tab-group>
<router-outlet name="admin-panel"></router-outlet>
```

AdminComponent.ts (changetab function)

```
public changeTab(e) {
    console.log("link: "+this.adminPages[e.index].link);
    this.router.navigate([this.adminPages[e.index].link]);
    // this.router.navigate(['account', {outlets: {'admin': [this.adminPages[e.index].link]}}]);
    // this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { admin: [this.adminPages[e.index].link] } }]);
}
```

Relevant part of the app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
      path: 'account',
      component: AccountComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full',
      children: [
         // { path: '', redirectTo: 'kategorier', pathMatch: 'full' },
         { path: 'ordrar', component: OrderManagerComponent, outlet: 'admin-panel' },
         { path: 'kategorier', component: CategoryManagerComponent, outlet: 'admin-panel' },
         { path: 'produkter', component: ProductManagerComponent, outlet: 'admin-panel' },
         { path: 'anvandare', component: UserManagerComponent, outlet: 'admin-panel' }
      ]
   },
   {
      path: '**',
      redirectTo: '/',
      pathMatch: 'full'

   }
];
```

If I am missing any relevant information, please let me know.

Comment: What is the contents of this.adminPages[e.index].link?

Comment: The contents of that variable was correct. I think it was "kategorier". I have found the solution now by my self, thank you Daryl for taking your time, I will post the answer as an answer to the question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake when I created this question. I didn't post all of my app-routing.module.ts file, I removed some parts to keep the question shorter, but that was a major mistake. Because the problem was within that file.

It looked something like this:

```
{path: ':kategori/:produkt', component: ProductDetailComponent },
{path: 'register',           component: RegisterComponent },
{path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'ordrar', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'ordrar',      component: OrderManagerComponent },
        { path: 'kategorier',  component: CategoryManagerComponent },
        { path: 'produkter',   component: ProductManagerComponent },
        { path: 'anvandare',   component: UserManagerComponent }
    ]
},
```

I know it's stupid to have a param at the start of the route but I have it at the moment anyways. But this is what caused my problem. When I went to the children of account, for example "account/kategorier", the route that was actually matched was the following:

```
{path: ':kategori/:produkt', component: ProductDetailComponent },
```

So my temporary solution was to move the path with the params down in the routes list to lower the priority. It is a bad solution but it'll do for now. It now looks like this:

```
{path: 'register',           component: RegisterComponent },
{path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'ordrar', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'ordrar',      component: OrderManagerComponent },
        { path: 'kategorier',  component: CategoryManagerComponent },
        { path: 'produkter',   component: ProductManagerComponent },
        { path: 'anvandare',   component: UserManagerComponent }
    ]
},
{path: ':kategori/:produkt', component: ProductDetailComponent },
```

Although I beileve the recommended solution would be to do it something like this:

```
{path: 'kategorier/:kategori/:produkt', component: ProductDetailComponent },
{path: 'register',           component: RegisterComponent },
{path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'ordrar', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'ordrar',      component: OrderManagerComponent },
        { path: 'kategorier',  component: CategoryManagerComponent },
        { path: 'produkter',   component: ProductManagerComponent },
        { path: 'anvandare',   component: UserManagerComponent }
    ]
},
```

So the lesson learnt from this is question is; when you make a question, make sure to not miss out on any potentially relevant information.